# Visual Studio - no merge GUI, only diff

Tags: git, visual-studio, merge, mergetool

I've been trying to manage my git repository from Visual Studio, but I'm stuck on merging branches.

Whenever there's a conflict I get a proper notification and after choosing the affected file, the button "Merge" appears, but that's when it gets confusing.

[Merge notification window and menu in Visual Studio Community](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4DGU.png)

First of all, pressing "Merge" causes VS to do some merging operations on its own followed by a message box like this one:

[Merge confirmation message box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2kBw.png)

Secondly, if I decide to fiddle with the file on my own and press "no" (or simply choose "compare files" from the previous menu) all I get is a diff file with no merging options (i.e. checkboxes, left/merge/right windows etc.).

So, it looks like this:

[diff window in Visual Studio Community](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En0in.png)

As I said - the standard merging tool in VS should have all the GUI sugar like checkboxes, 'keep left/right' or 'accept merge' buttons and such.

I can't get it to open though. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance, appreciate it.

Comment: What mergetool do you have configured?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, now I just feel stupid. Turns out I didn't provide some vital information about the issue. 
The whole purpose of this was to set up a secondary merge tool for Unity projects.

Therefore VS merge tool wasn't set as a default one in .git/config - Unity's automatic YAMLmerge was. VSDiffMerge was configured as a secondary "fallback" merge tool inside of Unity's config files. It should open if manual merging of the project is needed.

Anyway, the error lies somewhere inside my Unity config file - setting VSDiffMerge directly inside git's config made it work as a standalone tool in a 100% correct manner. Sorry for the fuss.